# Check that program logic is deterministic

Tags: c#, trace, deterministic

Don't know if this is right title for what I need. I need to run program with same input data few times and ensure that every time program take exactly the same path and produced exactly the same output. I even need to make sure that some iterator proccessed elements in same order.

Maybe there is some tools for that purpose? Or maybe there is some standard way what-to-do in order to check that? I put C# in tags because I need solution specifically for that language (and I'm coding in VS2012 if that can be of any help).

Edit:
Input of my program consists of list of integers and output is simple boolean. Even if I'll write tests - there can be very big difference in calculations and yet same result. I especially need to check that program code taken the same path every time.

Comment: Vs2012 has Tesing framework. Write you program logic as a method and test it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270865.aspx

Comment: Input of my program consists of list of integers and output is simple boolean. Even if I'll write tests - there can be very big difference in calculations and yet same result.

Comment: What do you think would be the sources on non-deterministic behaviour in your code?

Comment: @Dirk Dictionaries maybe or uninitialized variables somewhere.

Comment: @bobby C# doesn't allow uninizialized variables. How would dictionaries be non-deterministic? Do you require a specific order of items?

Comment: @Dirk Yes, things can go wrong if order is changed.

Comment: @bobby There is an [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) class in the .NET framework.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36224/discussion-between-dirk-and-bobby)

Answer (score 0):

You can use test framework and use mocks with excepts and asssert the output

Comment: Can you please check first post? I added info why I think that test will not work.

Comment: you can run on the same input over and over again and see that the path is the with mocks and the output with asserts i can't understand the problem.